# sum of eigenvalues bounds compact positive definite operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization

Let $A:H \to H$ a compact positive definite operator and $H$ Hilbert space.
Let ${\phi_1,...\phi_n}$ an orthonormal set in $H$.
We should prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \langle A\varphi_k,\varphi_k \rangle \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_k(A)$.

I tried induction and the minmax thm. but I did not yield any results.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: What is $\lambda_k(A)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $e_m$ be the basis of eigenvectors of $A$. Then
\begin{multline*}\sum_{k=1}^n (A\phi_k, \phi_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n (A \sum_{m=1}^\infty (\phi_k, e_m)e_m, \sum_{m=1}^\infty (\phi_k, e_m)e_m) = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{m=1}^\infty \lambda_m (\phi_k, e_m)^2 \\= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \lambda_m \sum_{k=1}^n (\phi_k, e_m)^2.
\end{multline*}
Note that

1. $\sum_{k=1}^n (\phi_k, e_m)^2 \le 1$ since $\phi_k$ is an orthonormal system.
2. $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n (\phi_k, e_m)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{m=1}^\infty(\phi_k, e_m)^2 = n.$

Since $\lambda_m$ is a decreasing sequence the maximum of
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \lambda_m \sum_{k=1}^n (\phi_k, e_m)^2$$
is achieved when $\sum_{k=1}^n (\phi_k, e_m)^2$ is $1$ for $m = 1, \ldots, n$ and $0$ otherwise and is equal to
$$\sum_{m=1}^n \lambda_m$$